# Sorting by column using character in middle of each cell, without helper column

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to sort a range by a column, but sort using a single character in the middle of the string in each cell?

So column looks like this:

```
red(7)
blue(4)
orange(9)
green(2)
etc..
```

I want to sort it using the number within the brackets.

My current code sorts the columns alphabetically:

```
With sheetSUMMARY

.Range(.Cells(summaryFirstRow, summaryReForenameCol)), _
    .Cells(summaryLastRow, summaryReColourCol))). _
Sort _
key1:=.Range(.Cells(summaryFirstRow, summaryReColourCol)), _
    .Cells(summaryLastRow, summaryReColourCol))), _
order1:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlNo

End With
```

So it looks like this:

```
blue(4)
green(2)
orange(9)
red(7)
```

Without making a helper column in excel (which extracts the numbers), is it possible to sort it like this purely programatically? (I haven't really got space for a helper column at this stage)

```
green(2)
blue(4)
red(7)
orange(9)
```

Comment: The easiest *is* with a "helper column" , which you could insert & then remove programmatically, so it would be invisible to the user, and would accomplish your goal ***much** more quickly*.  The helper column doesn't necessarily have to be next to it, or even on the same worksheet.

Comment: @ashleedawg If that's the case, then that's what I'll do. I just thought it was worth asking just in case there was some super easy solution that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: You could use arrays and do all the sorting there, but @ashleedawg's suggestions seems the most sensible.

Comment: Oh, it's definitely 100% do-able the other way... just depends how much time you want to spend on it!  It would be a great learning exercise -- in fact I have fond memories of writing my first [bubble-sort routine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), on a (Commodore 64](https://virtualconsoles.com/online-emulators/c64/) I think, before sorting algorithms were included in, well, everything.  (Sorry, that might sound like I'm mocking the idea -- fact is, there could very well be a *reason* you can't do it any other way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary` to store your values and their corresponding numbers and then there are a number of sorting methods. I opted to use an `ArrayList` to do the sorting rather than writing a bespoke sorting function.

```
Public Sub SortByNumber()
    Dim arrayList As Object, inputDictionary As Object, outputDictionary As Object 'late binding so you can drop the code in easily
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Dim num As Double
    Dim v As Variant

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")
    Set arrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set inputDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set outputDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'put current values into dictionary and arraylist
    For Each r In rng
        num = CLng(Mid(r.Value, InStr(r.Value, "(") + 1, Len(r.Value) - InStr(r.Value, "(") - 1))
        Do While inputDictionary.exists(num) 'avoid errors with duplicates numbers (see comments)
            num = num + 0.00000001
        Loop
        inputDictionary.Add Item:=r.Value, Key:=num
        arrayList.Add num
    Next r

    arrayList.Sort

    'use sorted arraylist to determine order of items in output dictionary
    For Each v In arrayList.toarray
        outputDictionary.Add Item:=v, Key:=inputDictionary.Item(v)
    Next v

    'output values to the next column -- just remove the offset to overwrite original values
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputDictionary.keys())
End Sub
```

---

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `System.Collections.ArrayList`? How does it work, is that a .NET object that works in VBA via late binding? Do you need any special libraries to use this?

Comment: ArrayLists are great - they are like collections except they have loads of useful functions where collections have pretty much none. No special libraries - just late bind or you can (manually, I think) make a reference and early bind too. Lots of good info here: http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Arraylist_en.html

Comment: I know they're great, I use them in Java all the time :) Thanks for the link!

Comment: Thank you, this is just the kind of thing I was looking for, and could never have worked out by myself!

Comment: @Slab, no problem -- it was an interesting question! If you have any questions about the solution just ask away :)

Comment: @CallumDA - What would happen if we change `blue(4)` to `blue(7)` with this solution?

Comment: @Vityata It would break. I didn't cater for that initially because there were no dupes in the example data. However, I've now added a simple while loop which avoids problems with (up to 100m) duplicate numbers - keeping them in their original order. Good question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something interesting, if you really do not want to add a helper column. Pretty much the following:

- let's say your `inputRange` is `Range("A1:A4")`
- declare a variant `virtualRange`, which would be a bit of a tricky - it would take the values of the `inputRange` and the next column:

  `virtualRange = Union(inputRange, inputRange.Offset(0, 1)).Value`
- then loop through your `inputRange` and assign the cell value to the second dimension of the `virtualRange`. It should pretty much look like this in the local window:

[image]

- Now the funny part - pass the virtualRange to the `SortDataBySecondValue` and it will return the `virtualRange` sorted. Here is a really important point - if you pass the `virtualRange` with parenthesis, like this `SortDataBySecondValue (virtualRange)` nothing useful would happen - the parenthesis overrule the `ByRef` argument in `SortDataBySecondValue()` and the `virtualRange` would remain untact.
- At the end you have your `virtualRange` sorted and you have to pass its values correctly to the inputRange. This is achievable with a simple loop:

  `For Each myCell In inputRange
      Dim cnt As Long
      cnt = cnt + 1
      myCell = virtualRange(cnt, 1)
  Next myCell`
- Now the `inputRange` is sorted as expected:

[image]

The whole code is here:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputRange      As Range
    Dim myCell          As Range
    Dim virtualRange    As Variant

    Set inputRange = Range("A1:A4")
    virtualRange = Union(inputRange, inputRange.Offset(0, 1)).Value

    For Each myCell In inputRange.Columns(1).Cells
        virtualRange(myCell.Row, 2) = locateNumber(myCell)
    Next myCell

    SortDataBySecondValue virtualRange

    For Each myCell In inputRange
        Dim cnt As Long
        cnt = cnt + 1
        myCell = virtualRange(cnt, 1)
    Next myCell

End Sub

Public Function locateNumber(ByVal s As String) As Long

    Dim startIndex As Long
    Dim endIndex As Long

    startIndex = InStr(1, s, "(") + 1
    endIndex = InStr(1, s, ")")
    locateNumber = Mid(s, startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)

End Function

Sub SortDataBySecondValue(ByRef Data As Variant)

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim temp            As Variant
    Dim sortBy          As Long: sortBy = 2

    ReDim temp(UBound(Data) - 1, sortBy)
    For i = LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)
        For j = i To UBound(Data)
            If Data(i, sortBy) > Data(j, sortBy) Then
                temp(i, 1) = Data(i, 1)
                temp(i, sortBy) = Data(i, sortBy)
                Data(i, 1) = Data(j, 1)
                Data(i, sortBy) = Data(j, sortBy)
                Data(j, 1) = temp(i, 1)
                Data(j, sortBy) = temp(i, sortBy)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub OrderByColumn()
Dim i As Long, tempColumn As Long, colorColumn As Long, color As String
'get table to variable
Dim tableToOrder As Range
'here ypou have to specify your own range!!
Set tableToOrder = Range("A1:C5")
colorColumn = tableToOrder.Column
tempColumn = colorColumn + tableToOrder.Columns.Count
'insert new column at the end of the table and populate with extracted numbers
Columns(tempColumn).Insert
For i = tableToOrder.Row To (tableToOrder.Rows.Count + tableToOrder.Row - 1)
    color = Cells(i, colorColumn).Value
    Cells(i, tempColumn).Value = Mid(color, InStr(1, color, "(") + 1, InStr(1, color, ")") - InStr(1, color, "(") - 1)
Next
i = i - 1 'now i points to last row in range
'order whole table accordingly to temporary column
Range(Cells(tableToOrder.Row, tableToOrder.Column), Cells(i, tempColumn)).Sort Key1:=Range(Cells(tableToOrder.Row, tempColumn), Cells(i, tempColumn))
'delete column
Columns(tempColumn).Delete
End Sub
```